# Tableview scroll is not stopping on tap if i animate tableview cells

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview

I am trying to add animations in tableview cells and the animations are working fine. But when i try to stop the scroll of tableview by tapping its not stopping. Usually in a scrolling tableview if we tap of screen the scroll would stop. But when i add these animations thats not working. below is the code i use for animations

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayCell cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let rotationTransform = CATransform3DScale(CATransform3DIdentity, 0.4, 0.4, 0)

    cell.layer.transform = rotationTransform
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5) { () -> Void in
        cell.layer.transform = CATransform3DIdentity
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey check my answer its tested & very well worked

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Note:**

This is normal behavior for animations using one of the animateWithDuration... method. Still if you want user interaction during the animation you can try like Below i have shown.

Simply you need to try like this :

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayCell cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let rotationTransform = CATransform3DScale(CATransform3DIdentity, 0.4, 0.4, 0)
    cell.layer.transform = rotationTransform

    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, delay: 0.5, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.AllowUserInteraction, animations: { () -> Void in
        cell.layer.transform = CATransform3DIdentity
        }, completion: nil)
}
```

Hope it will help to you.

Comment: Worked like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

The main thing you’re hitting here is that UIView animations, by default, disable touches on the animating views while an animation is in progress. You can change that behavior by switching to the `+animateWithDuration:options:delay:animations:completion:` method and adding the [UIViewAnimationOptions](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/#//apple_ref/c/tdef/UIViewAnimationOptions) value `AllowUserInteraction`, like this:

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, delay:0, options:[.AllowUserInteraction], animations:{ () -> Void in
    cell.layer.transform = CATransform3DIdentity
}, completion:nil)
```

Answer (score -1):

You could add a transparent UIView (the same size as the cell) above the animated views and once touched and/or when the animation is complete, remove the view from the subView.